# Триумвират — "союз трёх мужей", а если мужей двое или четверо?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Триумвират — «союз трёх мужей» (лат.) — три лидера совместно управляют страной.
А если их двое или четверо, есть ли тому название?

Comment: Дуумвират: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82 Здесь и в некоторых других статьях встречается слово квадроумвират http://newsland.com/user/4297669554/content/kogda-liudi-sozdavali-religii/4223002

Comment: Встречаются и менее формальные "тандем власти" и "квартет власти".

Comment: @Alex_ander,  Тандем — расположение один за другим. Участники по определению неравноправны. В определении дуумвирата этого нет. "Kвартет власти" — по-моему, хорошо.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, vir — *муж*. На мой взгляд, в статье по ссылке все "-вираты" употреблены некорректно (квадроумвират из банкиров, власти, религий и ученых и т. п.). Но само слово *квадроумвират* заслуживает внимания. Спасибо за ссылки.

Comment: Всё ещё сложнее, чем мне казалось. Порылся и сочинил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

В русских историографических текстах, наряду с распространённым "**триумвиратом**" латинского происхождения, используется таким же способом образованное слово "**дуумвират**" (правление двух мужей/человек; в Латыни *duum* - родительный падеж от *duo* - два) и слово **"кватуорвират"** (лат. *quattuorviratus*: quattuor = четыре, не склоняется). Пример:
http://www.nauka.x-pdf.ru/17istoriya/297859-23-istoriya-vostoka-shesti-tomah-glavnaya-redkollegiya-rbribakov-predsedatel-lbalaev-kzashrafyan-zamestiteli-predsedatelya.php

*Иное* значение имеет слово "**квадрумвират**" (quadrumvirato), заимствованное из современного итальянского языка. В Древнем Риме слово *quadrumviri* (*quadrum* на латыни - **квадрат**, viri - люди/мужи) означало выборный (на 5 лет) орган в Сенате, наделённый юридическими и полицейскими полномочиями), ср. "четырёхугольник" (совещательная единица в советское время на предприятиях). Позже в Италии так именовали хунту четырёх с участием Муссолини, захвативших власть (Квадрумвиры). 
https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrumvirato

В ряде русских текстов, тем не менее, это слово встречается в значении "кватуорвирата", что не совсем точно.